# Can pdf and doc files be opened in a browser using coldfusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, doc

Can a pdf file or a doc/docx file be opened in a browser? I have a link which when clicked opens up the document as such in pdf and in MS word. But is it possible to open them in browser using Coldfusion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that ColdFusion can address. This has to do with the particular web browser being used and what related software a user has installed locally.

If the user has a browser that supports PDF natively (e.g. Chrome) or they have the Adobe Acrobat browser plugin installed, then the PDF will open in the browser. Otherwise, it will open in the Acrobat program or any program they have that can view PDF documents. There is no MS Word plugin for browsers, so the browser will always try to open a .doc file in MS Word (if they have it installed) or any other program they have that can read that type of file.

Answer (score 11):

ColdFusion has little to do with how they are opened in the browser.  That depends on how the user's browser is configured.  If it is configured to open in a standalone app, then it will do so, if it is configured to open in the browser then it will do that.  You have some influence if you are serving the file via ColdFusion using the `<cfcontent>` tag, but since you have provided no code or any explanation of how you are serving these files I will assume you are just doing something like `<a href="/path/to/pdf.pdf">pdf</a>` which will just load the file in the browser and the browser determines whether to download it or view it directly.

If you are using `<cfcontent>` to serve the file then you can also use `<cfheader>` and send the file as either `inline` or an `attachment` which can help tell the browser how it should load it.  That said, it is still up to the browser's configuration.

Something like:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/pdf" />
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline;filename=mypdf.pdf;" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" reset="true" variable="#myPDFBinary#" />
```

would serve a PDF binary, telling the browser to load it inline, which should, if properly configured, open the PDF in the browser.

Comment: thank you all for your responses! really appreciate them. thanks